# React native multiple action sheet in single component class component working fine in android but in ios not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react native action sheets npm for cross platform action sheet.In my project there is a flow where four action sheets will open based on onclick one after other.

This flow is working fine in android but in ios i am not being able to open action sheets programatically.Any help is appreciated

Please check the onPress functions 
a) openRequestTypeActionSheet
b) openPaymentTypeActionSheet 
c) openPaymentTypeActionSheet1

```
import React, { createRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, StatusBar, Image, Dimensions, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Platform } from 'react-native';
import ActionSheet from "react-native-actions-sheet";

const actionSheetRef = createRef();
const actionSheetRef1 = createRef();
const actionSheetRef2 = createRef();
const actionSheetRef5 = createRef();


export default class Map extends React.Component {
    
     openRequestTypeActionSheet = () => {
        actionSheetRef2.current?.setModalVisible(false)
        setTimeout(() => { actionSheetRef.current?.setModalVisible(true) }, 100);
    }

    openPaymentTypeActionSheet = () => {
        actionSheetRef5.current?.setModalVisible(false)
        setTimeout(() => { actionSheetRef2.current?.setModalVisible(true) }, 100);
    }

    openPaymentTypeActionSheet1 = () => {
        actionSheetRef1.current?.setModalVisible(false)
        setTimeout(() => { actionSheetRef2.current?.setModalVisible(true) }, 100);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user ExtraOverlayComponent with this formation:

```
<ActionSheet 
.....
ExtraOverlayComponent ={exteraactionsheet()}
.....
/>
```